# How jdbc connectvity should work in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Below is the way, i am using jdbc connectivity for my spring mvc.
I have some technical doubts, which follows-

> 1.

As i have invoked datasource object in every bean that requires db connectivity. Is it the right way of doing it? 
What if i don't want a particular repository object to be instantiated when the application starts up
(because I'm not sure when user will invoke the object, so why instantiate it at the very beginning)?

```
<bean 
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jdbc.testConnection}" />
    </bean>

<bean id="ustestuthenticationRepository" 
                class="com.test.repository.impl.UstestuthenticationRepositoryImpl">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="someclass" 
                class="com.test.repository.impl.someclass">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

> 2.

```
@Qualifier("dbDataSource")
    private static DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
```

and then creating

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of invoking datasource.If each and every Repository object creates separate jdbctemplate, is it something appropriate?

In every repository class, i am invoking datasource in the folowing way-

> **Modified Code**

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg  ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

<bean id="someclass" class="com.era.repository.impl.someclass">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>
```

and implementation in someclass is -

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

then only accessing jdbcTemplate variable wherever is required.
Am i doing it correctly now? Please advise.

Comment: Why don't you create one JdbcTemplate and inject it into all your repositories?

Comment: @beny23 care to show one example please.unfortunately i'm not expert on this. i'm kind of learning and developing. I sensed some issue with my way of making this connection thats why need your help :) you can give me any link also, where i can learn it. Many thanks.

Comment: its easy, instead of having DataSource properties in your objects, just have JdbcTemplate ones.

Comment: @beny23 I have modified the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

What you done is not an error. It is possible to work that way.
However.
It means you will simply work with JDBC directly.
It means, you need handle transactions "manually".
It is hard and a lot of code.

You better use spring data and hibernate.
Or spring data and JPA.
Anyway, spring data will help you to manage all resources and will simplify data access for you.

If you already on spring MVC, take also spring data. Why bother?
Official spring data example:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: @Nabokov again I have no idea how to do that. If it is not a big deal for you please give me an example or a link where i can learn it. Many thanks.

Comment: added link to example

Comment: Note, there is no need to handle transactions manually with JdbcTemplate.  @Transactional annotations are enough...  And JPA or spring data is not always better, it very much depends on the use case.

Comment: @Nabokov i have gone through the reference link. But its not very easy for me to implement it as of now, i have to know all the db table mappings and have to create similar entities in spring side, which i can't do now.My question is can't the transaction, connection pooling, query exception handling be done by spring mvc only? I have used c3p0 connection pooling.

Comment: I think you can do it with JdbcTemplate, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SpringJDBC/article.html

but I'm not experienced with it.